# Align li element to right

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to move one of my li elements to the right, i looked at other solutions but they are not working. `li.right{ text-align: right;}` should work, but maybe it is canceled by previous css ?

```
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div id="navbar container">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#">Mac</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Iphone</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Ipad</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Watch</a></li>
                <li class="right"><a href="#">Log In</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </nav>
</body>
```

Here is CSS

```
.navbar {
    min-height:32px !important
}

.navbar .navbar-nav {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
  vertical-align: top;
}


.navbar{
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 5px;
}

.navbar{
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-size: 20px;
}

li.right{
    text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: Do you want to keep the other elements centered?

Comment: Please provide working example. Before that, since u use bootstrap, u can try to add the class  `pull-right` to the `li` element u want to align.

Comment: If you want it to the right, why are you centering it? `.navbar{
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 5px;
}`

Comment: I am centering it because i want other elements to be in center.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's cleaner to use the bootstrap built in classes, that are designed for this purpose:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div id="navbar container">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#">Mac</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Iphone</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Ipad</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Watch</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#">Log In</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: That works, thanks, But I wonder why `li.right{ float: right;}` doesn't work.

Comment: LIkely because the style isnt specific enough, if you look at the bootstrap css you'll notice they cascade down through `.navbar-nav > li` - your style is less specific than this, if you were to use `.navbar-nav li.right` then it would work. Saying that, using bootstraps built in classes is far better :)

Comment: Not really, it's his `<ul>`. It gets restricted to the maximum width of all list elements, and therefor doesn't allow the individual item to be floating to the absolute right of the container.

Comment: @Roberrrt If the `ul.navbar` is floated left you'd be right, otherwise wrong.

Comment: Lol @Roberrrt - you over ride the ul to have `display:inline-block` - and _still_ are using `text-align:right`, when you need `float:right`! :)  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dOgxzw

Comment: True, but this floats the remaining elements to the left :(.

Comment: And how do I add padding to the element on the right ? I tried `.navbar-right{ padding-right: 15px; }` but it moves everything to the left. Is it because I have `navbar` class as `inline-block` ?

Comment: That doesn't do anyhing.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `float:right` property

```css
.navbar {
    min-height:32px !important
}

.navbar .navbar-nav {
  list-style-type:none;
  float: none;
  vertical-align: top;
}


.navbar{
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 5px;
}

.navbar{
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-size: 20px;
}

li.right{
    float: right;
}
```

```html
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div id="navbar container">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#">Mac</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Iphone</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Ipad</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Watch</a></li>
                <li class="right"><a href="#">Log In</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </nav>
```